# Can't install subclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I keep getting the following error when trying to install subclipse via Eclipse installer

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.doc_1.3.0.jar.
Bad chunk size: 
Unable to read repository at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18.jar.
Bad chunk size:

I use the following URL to get the package 
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

And I have Eclipse V 3.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like network issues.  Just download the zipped update site and install from a Local Archive instead of a URL.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed no repositories at those locations, so the question is where you are finding those paths. open "Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites" and remove related links. This worked for me.